# How to Convert Infix to Postfix Expression in Stack C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, parsing, data-structures

I am building a program in OOP C++ that will convert an Infix to Postfix expression using predefined Stackitem and Stack classes ( these two classes work fine). But I have some problems in the implementation of conversion algorithm. I cannot get the expected output for some inputs.

I have tried to implement the following algorithm:

Basic steps, while parsing the infix expression:

- if the item is an operand, output immediately
- if the item is a left parenthesis, push onto the stack
- if the item is a right parenthesis pop the stack and output the contents until a left parenthesis (parenthesis is popped but not output)
- if the item is an operator, pop and output all the operators with higher or equal precendence, then push the item onto the stack
- just push the item onto the stack, if the stack is empty or the top element is a left parenthesis or if the top element has a lower precendence.

Stackitem class implementation which helps in decesiding wheather the item is operator, operand, and its precedence (by giving an integer)

```
#include "StackItem.h"

StackItem::StackItem(bool isOp, int i) {
    init(isOp, i);
    next = 0;
}

StackItem::StackItem(string item) {
    if(item.compare("+") == 0)
        init(true, OPERATOR_PLUS);
    else if(item.compare("-") == 0)
        init(true, OPERATOR_MINUS);
    else if(item.compare("*") == 0)
        init(true, OPERATOR_MULTIPLICATION);
    else if(item.compare("/") == 0)
        init(true, OPERATOR_DIVISION);
    else if(item.compare("(") == 0)
        init(true, OPERATOR_LEFTPAR);
    else if(item.compare(")") == 0)
        init(true, OPERATOR_RIGHTPAR);
    else
        init(false, atoi(item.c_str()));
}

void StackItem::init(bool isOp, int i) {
    isOperator = isOp;
    if(isOp)
        op = i;
    else
        n = i;
}

string StackItem::toString() {
    stringstream ss;

    if(!isOperator) {
        ss << n;
    } else {
        switch(op) {
            case OPERATOR_MINUS:
                ss << "-";
                break;
            case OPERATOR_PLUS:
                ss << "+";
                break;
            case OPERATOR_DIVISION:
                ss << "/";
                break;
            case OPERATOR_MULTIPLICATION:
                ss << "*";
                break;
            case OPERATOR_LEFTPAR:
                ss << "(";
                break;
            case OPERATOR_RIGHTPAR:
                ss << ")";
                break;
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

And here is the problematic code ( for conversion ). I am suspecting that the problem is with my ( fifth and sixth point of the algorithm steps)

```
#include "Calculator.h"
#include <iostream>

Calculator::Calculator( string expression ) {
    infixExpression = expression;
    stack = new Stack();
    istringstream iss( expression );
    string token;
    iss >> token;
    postfixExpression = "";

    while ( token.compare( ";" ) != 0 ) {
        cout << "token:" << token << endl;
        StackItem *item = new StackItem( token );

        if ( !item->isOperator ) {
            postfixExpression += item->toString() + " ";
        } else {
            if ( item->op == OPERATOR_LEFTPAR )
                stack->push( item );
            else if ( item->op == OPERATOR_RIGHTPAR ) {
                while ( !stack->isEmpty() && stack->top() != OPERATOR_LEFTPAR ) {
                    string s = stack->top()->toString();
                    delete stack->pop();
                    postfixExpression += s + " ";

                }
                string s = stack->top()->toString();
                delete stack->pop();
            } else {
                while ( !stack->isEmpty() && ( item->op <= stack->top()->op ) ) {
                    if ( stack->top()->isOperator ) {
                        string s = stack->top()->toString();
                        delete stack->pop();
                        postfixExpression += s + " ";
                    }
                    break;
                }
                while ( ( stack->isEmpty() ) || ( stack->top()->op == OPERATOR_LEFTPAR ) || ( stack->top()->op < item->op ) ) {
                    stack->push( item );
                }
            }
        }
        iss >> token;
    }

    while ( !stack->isEmpty() ) {
        string s = stack->top()->toString();
        delete stack->pop();
        postfixExpression += s + " ";
    }

    postfixExpression += ";";
}

string Calculator::getPostfix() {
    return postfixExpression;
}
```

The required inputs and outputs has to be parsed according to ";" at the end and a white space has to be left between each input and output part.
Example:

Input: 1 + 2 + 3 ;

Output: 1 2 + 3 + ; ( this works fine)

However,
Input : ( 1 + 2 ) ;

Output : Nothing ( it gives return some memory address)

Also for:
Input : 10 + 10 * 40 - 45 / 5 ;

Output : 10 10 4 * 45 5 / + ;

Which is a wrong order!

Edit: The operator defines are as follows:

```
#define OPERATOR_LEFTPAR        0
#define OPERATOR_RIGHTPAR       1
#define OPERATOR_MINUS          2
#define OPERATOR_PLUS           3
#define OPERATOR_DIVISION       4
#define OPERATOR_MULTIPLICATION 5
```

Edit: This new code solved many problems with basic and short inputs, still very large and complicated expressions crash in the output.

```
#include "Calculator.h"
#include <iostream>

Calculator::Calculator(string expression)
{

    infixExpression=expression;
    stack = new Stack();
    istringstream iss(expression);
    string token;
     iss >> token;
     postfixExpression="";

    while(token.compare(";") != 0)
    {
        //cout << "token:"<<token << endl;
        StackItem* item=new StackItem(token);

        if(!item->isOperator){
            postfixExpression += item->toString() + " ";

        }
         else
        {
            if(item->op == OPERATOR_LEFTPAR)
                    stack->push(item);
            else if(item->op == OPERATOR_RIGHTPAR)
            {
                while(!stack->isEmpty()&& stack->top()->op != OPERATOR_LEFTPAR)
                {
                    string s = stack->top()->toString();
                    delete stack->pop();
                    postfixExpression +=s+" ";

                }

                string s = stack->top()->toString();
                delete stack->pop();
            }
            else
            {
                while((!stack->isEmpty()) && item->op <= stack->top()->op)
                {
                     string s = stack->top()->toString();
                     delete stack->pop();
                     postfixExpression +=s+" ";

                }

                while((stack->isEmpty()) || item->op > stack->top()->op || stack->top()->op==OPERATOR_LEFTPAR)
                {
                    stack->push(item);
                }


            }

        }
        iss >> token;
    }


    while(!stack->isEmpty())
    {

         string s = stack->top()->toString();
        delete stack->pop();
        postfixExpression +=s+" ";
    }

    postfixExpression += ";";
}



string Calculator::getPostfix()
{



     return postfixExpression;

}
```

Comment: Might be missing something here, but why is there a `break` in the first `while` of the last `else`? The loop will run at most once because of this `break` which does not seem right.

Comment: *I cannot get the expected output for some inputs.* -- Use the debugger and single-step through your program to see where the program diverges from your expectations.

Comment: That break is unnecessary you are right. But it does not affect the main problem.

Comment: Also, this program requires no user memory allocation.  Why are you not simply using `std::stack<std::string>` or even `std::stack<char>`?  This `new` and `delete` overcomplicates a rather simple program.

Comment: My input size is not fixed. Also I need learning memory allocation for data structures applications.

Comment: *My input size is not fixed* -- This has nothing to do with using `std::stack`.   *Also I need learning memory allocation for data structures applications.* -- You can write the very same program you're attempting to write with no allocations on your end whatsoever.  That is the goal of a C++ program, and that is to reduce, if not eliminate having to handle raw memory.  Even if it is a data structure, why have you not encapsulated your home-made `stack` class to do the allocations, instead of strewing the allocations around all over the code?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  The code you posted is incomplete.  Second, the reason you should first use `std::stack` without any dynamic allocation is to *quickly prototype* your solution.  Right now you have no idea which part of your code is faulty -- it could be the stack logic, could be erroneous memory handling (you even have output that shows an address), etc.  Once you get it working using bug-free components such as `std::stack`, then you go back and implement the same steps using your homemade class.

Comment: If you load your program in the debugger and single-step through it, you'll probably find your problem in a matter of minutes. If you don't know how to use the debugger, this is a perfect opportunity to learn.

Comment: Your last `while` statement: `while ( ( stack->isEmpty() ) || ( stack->top()->op == OPERATOR_LEFTPAR ) || ( stack->top()->op < item->op ) ) {` is unnecessary. The rules say that you will unconditionally push that operator onto the stack. So eliminate the `while` loop and just write `stack->push(item)`. That won't solve your problem, but it does simplify the code.

Comment: Thanks Jim and Paul for your advises. I will consider them .